# Cisco AnyConnect VPN installation error

Tags: vpn, cisco

While installing Cisco AnyConnect the following error message appears in a dialog box.

Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client

The VPN client agent was unable to create the interprocess communication depot
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution one**

```
Press Win + R 
Type: services.msc and press Enter
Find Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)
Stop the service
Right-click and open the service's Properties
Change the Startup type: to Disabled
Reboot the computer
Install Cisco AnyConnect VPN
```

**Solution Two**

```
Click the Windows Start button.
Click on Control Panel.
Set View by: to Category.
Click on View network status and tasks under Network and Internet.
Click on Change adapter settings.
Look for Shared in the Status column in the Network Connections window and right-click that device (e.g. Ethernet adapter, WiFi adapter) and click Properties.
Click the Sharing tab.
Clear the Allow other network users to connect through this computer’s Internet connection check box.
Click OK.
Reinstall Cisco AnyConnect.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable Internet Connection Sharing first (how - described above) and run installation as local administrator.